# .NET WPF set combobox selected item

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am setting items in a combobox with this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myItems = await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<int, string>>();
myCmb.Items.Clear();
myCmb.ItemsSource = myItems;
myCmb.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
myCmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
```

Then I want to select item by Key (for example, select item with Key=5) in another part of the code. How can this be done?

Answer (score -1):

```
myCmb.SelectedItem = myItems.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Key == desiredKey);
```

You can do it this way but you will need to have `myItems` accessible from the another part of code.